# How can i trigger a jquery event on an input based on the class of the surrounding p tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would i trigger an event when the user clicks inside the text field below.
The problem I have is the only tag I can add id/class to is the

which sits outside the actual form field.

```
<p class="trigger">
<input type="text" name="test">
</p>
```

I don't want a generic trigger on input tag this is not suitable

```
$(input).focus(function() {
  alert('triggered');
});
```

it really needs to be associated with the p class 'trigger'
any help would be fantastic

Comment: Have you tried using the class selector? `$(".trigger")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('.trigger input').focus(function() {
  alert('triggered');
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/HB7Pz/)**